# What is this view controller method

Tags: objective-c

Xcode's own Game template has a view controller method called 'view' that is a message, not a property:

```
if ([self isViewLoaded] && ([[self view] window] == nil)) {
```

I cannot find this method in the documentation for the GLKViewController or any of its super class. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `view` property. A property is really just a setter and getter method (or just a getter if it's read-only).

Properties and the property accessor syntax is just a convenience.

A call to the `view` property (`self.view`) is really a call to the getter method: `[self view]`.

Same for the `window` call.

The line you posted can easily (and equally) be written as:

```
if ([self isViewLoaded] && self.view.window == nil) {
```